# Multifield inputs request in node js server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

My frontend request form request get me this

```
req.body {
  name: ["abc","ggg"],
  class: ["A","B"],
  bloodGroup: ["A+","B-"]
}
```

I had try will my code to solve the problem like this

```
let arr = [];
req.body.name.forEach((item, index)=>{
  arr.push({
     name: item,
     class: req.body.class[index],
     bloodGroup: req.body.bloodGroup[index]
  })
})
return arr;
```

Is there any other way like dynamically, I will pass only my request and it will return me objects of these data

this is sample req.body there will be multiple more data in each key
name, class, bloodGroup
ex:

```
name ["a","b","c",...] so on...
class ["ab","bc","dc",...] so on...
bloodGroup ["a+","b+","c-",...] so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the first property of the request body.

We then use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on req.body and map it to return only the correct entry for each index. We then use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create each object.

This means that however many properties are present on req.body, they will be present on the result objects.

```js
const req = { 
    body: {
      name: ["abc","ggg", "ccc"],
      class: ["A","B", "C"],
      bloodGroup: ["A+","B-", "C-"],
      height: [175, 182, 190]
   }
}

const arr = Object.values(req.body)[0].map((item, index) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(req.body).map(([key, properties]) => ([key, properties[index]]));
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: but it breaking up in multiple data
my question is 

const req = { 
    body: {
      name: ["abc","ggg","ccc"],
      class: ["A","B","C"],
      bloodGroup: ["A+","B-","C-"],
      height: [175, 182, 190]
   }
}

the name, class, bloodGroup, height can have multiple data at same time so the code will make 3 objects accoridng to it

Comment: Thanks for checking out my answer! Could you maybe update your question with the shape of the data you require? Thank you!!

Comment: I've updated the code, I think this corrects as least one of the issues! Thanks!